# Rails 7 importmaps fullcalendar 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, import-maps

I need help with following code:

*Rails 7.0.3*

### view.html.erb

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

### importmap.rb

```
pin "fullcalendar", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.js"
```

### javascript/application.js

```
import "fullcalendar"
```

### javascript/controllers/fullcalendar_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import FullCalendar from 'fullcalendar'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    calendar.render();
  }
}
```

### layouts/applications.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```

And the output... :(

***Failed to register controller: fullcalendar (controllers/fullcalendar_controller)***

***ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at main.js? [sm]:20877:37****

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with calendar js file, you can download the fullcalendar js file to your local project, `./bin/importmap pin fullcalendar --download` and then you can see fullcalendar.js file under vendors directory `vendors/javascript/fullcalendar.js` then replace that js file content with the full_calendar source `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.2/main.js` finally add export line to end of the fullcalendar.js file `export default FullCalendar;`. Hope it may help you with your issue.